# how to transfer/migrate data from Source Oracle DB to aws oracle rds

Tags: amazon-rds

I have a request to move Source Oracle DB into AWS Oracle RDS. I research on AWS page to find out the solution, but AWS guide very complex such as upload dump file to S3, download file dump...I don't want to do on this way because it very take time. Any one have any solution to move database to AWS Oracle RDS?

My updated: Source Oracle DB is not use any AWS service. It only installed on phycical server.

Please help share any solution/tools can use to migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Developer Tool to copy database from source to AWS Oracle RDS (I am using SQL Developer Tool version 19.2.1.247)
[image]

Before migrate you need the below things to prepare/configure on AWS Oracle RDS, to ensure the same with Source Oracle DB

1. Create the same user who assigned to your schema/database
2. If Source Oracle DB is using tablespace, you must be create the same tablespace

After prepared, You will do the below steps on SQL Developer Tool

1. Using admin account to created a connect to Source Oracle DB server.
2. Using admin account to created a connect to Oracle AWS server.
   [image]
3. Go to Tools -> Database Copy...
   [image]
4. On Dialog, choose source db and destination db
   [image]

   INFO:If you are using tablespace on source db, you must be choose [Tablespace Copy] like that:

   [image]
5. Click Next to continue and waiting to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS native Database Migration Service (AWS DMS). Below is the link to the AWS DMS workshop.

https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/77bdff4f-2d9e-4d68-99ba-248ea95b3aca/en-US/oracle-oracle/data-migration

In the link, source database is mentioned as AWS RDS, but you can connect to any source database at on-premises or other locations. All you need is connectivity (between source Oracle and AWS target RDS Oracle) along with source database host IP, database port and db user credentials with necessary permissions to pull data from source. Usually for database migrations a direct connect is recommended to avoid data transfer related issues, but can also be done over VPN (can be slow for large migrations)

Start with the pre-requisites (permissions, grants etc.) to prepare the source database for migration as mentioned in the link above.

Other tools to explore would be to use Database native tools, like for Oracle we get Data Pump (export/import), for which we will have to use S3 for dumping the source data and then importing into AWS RDS from S3. This may be ok for one time activity. But for large number of migrations AWS DMS with a stable connectivity is the way to go.

Third option I can think of is use of AWS Snowball, if there is no reliable connectivity between source and AWS for large data transfer. AWS Snowball edge storage can be requested to your db location and hooked up to the network. Dump the database export into the Snowball and ship it back to AWS. They will copy the DB dump to a S3 bucket and from there we can import it into RDS.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my Source Oracle DB is not use AWS service

Comment: It need not be on AWS, like I mentioned, as long as you have connectivity we can use AWS DMS to connect to your source database. Source database can be anywhere.